# What could be the reason if the AC coupling option goes away when I attach a differential probe (P6248) to a Tek MSO5204 scope?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, oscilloscope, differential, ripple

When the scope is not attached, I could see both AC coupling and DC coupling options for the  channel settings. The moment I attach the differential probe, the AC coupling option goes away. Any reason?

This was part of an experiment to measure the ripple of a voltage regulator output.

Comment: how can you measure the difference between two signals if you remove the DC component from the signals?

Comment: well you could measure the AC difference...